# How to get in code the From email address in SugarCRM

Tags: email, phpmailer, sugarcrm

Is there any way to get the From email address via code in PHP - the address which we are using to send the email from SugarCRM.

I have tried

```
$phpMailer = new SugarPHPMailer();
$phpMailer->setMailerForSystem();       
print_r($phpMailer->From);
```

but it displays only the default value i.e. root@localhost

if i configure the From as shown below

```
$phpMailer->From = "myemailaddress@server.com";
print_r($phpMailer->From);
```

it display myemailaddress@server.com but when i recieve the email in my Gmail account it is received from the default configured email address of the Sugar which in our case is something@gmail.com i am sorry for privacy reasons i cant display it here
[image]

If i further elaborates the received mail and check the Show Original option from the menu in Gmail (the Menu available on the right side next to the fancy arrow of Reply where the from email address is displayed in Gmail) it displays From as the defualt email address of Sugar configured by us and Return-Path: myemailaddress@server.com

Any idea how to get the default configured Email address for sending emails in the Sugar via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$administration  = new Administration();
$administration->retrieveSettings();
print_r($administration->settings);
```